# Get the class on which the annotation is applied

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, web, annotations

I am building a custom annotation inside which there is a field of Class type. How do I set a value in it while using the annotation?
Code is given below :

```
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
    public @interface SpringCache {
        String putIt();
        String getIt();
        Class c();
    }
```

This  is my custom annotation. Now while I use it how do I give class to variable "c"?

```
    @SpringCache(putIt="I'm put", getIt="I'm get", c=<??>)
    public class TestSpringCache {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

As in this case I want c=TestSpringCache.class.

Comment: did you try `c=TestSpringCache.class`?

Comment: What you are trying to do is pointless. To get annotation you have to get reference to the class first `getClass().getAnnotation(...)`, so you do not need to store current class, as this class you will optain during process of annotation discovering.

Comment: but what if I want to get the class which used @myCustomAnnotation as annotation...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I didn't find the solution for this. As said by many it does not seem to be possible. Though I have found a work around this.

I removed the class type and kept only String and Boolean type variable there, and to get the annotated classes I took the path from the user to the package containing classes with the defined annotation. And then for each class in the package I checked for the annotation. If annotation was present I did what I wanted to, else did nothing.

Thanks to everyone for giving your time to this.

Answer (score 3):

You just write the class you want:

```
@SpringCache(putIt="I'm put", getIt="I'm get", c=TestSpringCache.class)
public class TestSpringCache {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println();
    }
}
```

You might have to add an import statement, if it is not in the same package.

Comment: +1 Java doesn't have a shortcut for "the current class" or "the class which I'm annotating".

Comment: So there ain't  a way to get the currently annotated class??

Comment: @Jack thanks for your time and efforts you made to answer but this is not what I was looking for...

Comment: @HVT7 What is it you are really looking for then? It doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have to optain all class instances from `ApplicationContext` (you can inject it), `ctx.getBean()`. There you can check if an annotation is present.